# How to create edmx avoiding sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe installation dependency

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, system.data.sqlite

I have designed an app using EF6 and Sqlite. I had already downloaded EF6 and Sqlite for Windows Runtime (System.Data.Sqlite) from NuGet package installations. But as still Sqlite was not coming in the Provider list to generate Entity Framework model from db using its configuration dialog, I installed `sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe` from Sqlite.org. With the installation, Sqlite provider is added in the Provider list and using that my edmx file has been generated and the SSDL generated like this

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="MyModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SQLite" ProviderManifestToken="ISO8601" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="MyModelStoreContainer">..</EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="XXX"></EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
```

Other than this, every where in my project, I used all the assembly references localy(NuGet downloaded local assembly path)  like this,

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>.\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
  <HintPath>.\packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.91.3\lib\net40\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite.EF6">
  <HintPath>.\packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.91.3\lib\net40\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

after successful generation of my edmx and working properly with my application, I want to uninstall the sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle from my pc to avoid any kind of dpendency(any assembly reference from GAC due to that installation) at deployment side.
But after the uninstallation, I get an error

```
Error   5   Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.  ..\EntityFramework\MyModel.edmx
```

It seems the error is pointing a missing GAC assembly reference for Sqlite provider at edmx storage model. My question is how can I remove the dependency of the that tool once my edmx is generated. Can it be resolved by adding any new assemly reference at the project or specific reference (how) to my existing local assembly (System.Data.Sqlite). Or any modification required at the app.config?

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
   <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
   <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
   <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
   <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
 </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyModelEntity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.MyModel.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\Database\SqliteDB.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```